# JSF a4j:commandLink component doesn't work inside a4j:repeat

Tags: jsf, seam, ajax4jsf

I have such code in my JSF template:

```
    <h:form>
    <table id="users" cellspacing="0">
    <a4j:repeat var="person" value="#{personList}">
    <tr>
    <td class="col1">
    <a4j:commandLink 
disabled="#{!canCreatePerson}" 
styleClass="#{canCreatePerson ? '' : 'inactive_link'}" 
action="#{adminPageController.create}"  
reRender="user-dialog-region" 
timeout="5000" 
limitToList="true" 
ignoreDupResponses="true" 
title="#{canCreatePerson ? messages['edit_user'] : ''}" 
onclick="if (!ajaxSubmissionAllowed) {return false;} 
ajaxSubmissionAllowed=false;" 
oncomplete="ajaxSubmissionAllowed=true;"> 
<h:outputText id="userName" value="#{person.name}"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </h:form>
```

This perfectly works outside the a4j:repeat tag, but no action performs inside a4j:repeat like it's implemented in my template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in SCOPE type of the variable personList, it was CONVERSATION, after I've changed it to PAGE everything works fine.
It's strange that I didn't see any error from SEAM.